# Does "You need to not eat much so that you will not be fat" have the same idea as "You shouldn't eat much so that you will not be fat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, semi-modals

All examples are mine:

**(1)** *You **should not** eat much so that you will not be fat*.
I want to use "*need*" and "*not*" in the first clause instead of "*should*" and "*not*", remaining the general idea of the sentence.

**(2)** *You **needn't** eat much so that you will not be fat*.
As far as I understood, (2) doesn't remain the idea of (1) because means:
**(3)** *It's not necessary for you to eat much so that you will not be fat*.

**(4)** *You **don't need to** eat much so that you will not be fat*.
As far as I understood, (4) doesn't remain the idea of (1) because it means (3), i. e. the same as (2).

**(5)** *You **need to not** eat much so that you will not be fat*.
As far as I understood, (5) remains the idea of (1).

Am I right?
If not, then why not?

Comment: You do not need to eat ***so*** much, otherwise you will become fat.

Comment: @WeatherVane As far as I know, your sentence "_You don't need to eat so much, otherwise you will become fat_" means "_It's not necessary for you to eat so much, otherwise you will become fat_", which is different from the idea of (1). Why am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, (1) asks *I want to use "need" and "not" in the first clause instead of "should" and "not"*, which I did. Another attempt is **You need to eat less, or you will become fat**. To me they all mean the same thing, every one of them, but they don't say it very well.

Comment: ... but if you are making a general statement that eating too much will make you fat (which everbody knows), then make it clear that you are not giving *particular* advice to someone.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, you wrote something I don't know how to connect with the questions I asked.

Comment: @Lovii (1) should be *either* "You **should not** eat so much that you become fat" *or* "You **should not** eat much, so that you will not be fat." These have different meanings. The first version means that you shouldn't *overeat*; the second implies you should *undereat*. For that reason, I believe the first version would be better to convey the meaning you intend.

Comment: If you *did* mean the second version, it needs a comma between the main clause and result clause.

Comment: Your sentences (2) and (3) could mean the same as the second version of (1) from my first comment, **if** they had a comma between the clauses. As it is currently written, (5) means the same as (2) and (3), *not* the same as the first version of (1). If you want it to have the same meaning as (1), you could change it to: "You need to not eat **too** much, so that you will not be fat," *or* "You need to not eat **so** much that you become fat."

Comment: I think you're getting confused between the two different functions of the word **so** that are possible in your sentences' context. The first usage would be in the expression "**so** much that [result]" (e.g. "so much that you become fat"), where **so** is an adverb of degree, modifying "much." The second usage would be **so** as a **conjunction** introducing a **result clause**: "...much, **so** that you become fat."

Comment: Choosing to use multiple "not" negations is confusing. It's best to word things with either 0 or 1 "not", and stop.  "Eating too much will cause you to be fat."  (0 nots).  "You should not eat too much, in order to avoid getting fat." (1 not). Getting into 2+ nots can potentially lead to "double negation" in English, and so it triggers alarm bells.   English isn't like Spanish where you an say "no" multiple times, just for fun.  The nots might contradict each other.  But mainly, they obfuscate the meaning, and so better to avoid when possible.

Comment: Everywhere you say "remain", I believe you mean "[retain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retain)". "Remain" is an intransitive verb, so whatever you mean, it's wrong here.